# MYSQL Transactions question, with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, transactions

I would like to use transaction in some critical areas of my code, but really not for everything I do.
I just learnt that there is an AUTOCOMMIT value that is set to 1 by default, and I should set it to 0 if I want to START TRANSACTION and COMMIT or ROLLBACK.

- Is there a better way to handle that autocommit?
- How do I know if it is set or not ?
- Does it's value change to AUTOCOMMIT=1 on every page that loads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using PDO

```
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$pdo->beginTransaction();
try {
    // do stuff
    $pdo->commit();
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    $pdo->rollBack();
    throw $ex;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was reading about PDO and I think I will take the time to use it. But as things are right now, would you say that defining a AUTOCOMMIT=1 on my START_TRANSACTION() and AUTOCOMMIT=0 on my ROLLBACK() and COMMIT() functions, is that a way to go about this ?

Comment: @Ted No, use the best tools available. Right now, that tool is PDO

Comment: the `$pdo->beginTransaction()` itself needs a try...catch block. For it may happen that a transaction is already in place, and asking to start a new transaction on an engine which does not support nested transactions can lead to triggering of an error

Comment: @Sudhi I've assumed that exception handling would be a part of the larger application. The one thrown in the transaction catch block would need to be caught somewhere as well.